# Android move Button always to center

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a little Chat application. At the bottom is the EditText line and a send button. In the EditText maxLines is set to 5. How can I move the button always to center_horizontal, even if new lines (1-5) are added to the textview? The button actually just stays at it's position.

My try:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtChatline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:hint="@string/hint_message"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="500"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `EditText` grows vertically, you need to use `android:gravity="center_vertical"`.

(or `android:gravity="center"` if you want to use both, but I assume it was a mistake).

Comment: Oh my god that was the problem. Shame on me :D Thank you! I can accept the answer in 4 minutes